# How to fix bug found by find bugs

Tags: java, find, boolean

The following is code I have to do secure analysis, find bugs found a bug in this method.

```
 // Equals Method
    public boolean equals(Date dateIn){
       if(day == dateIn.day && month == dateIn.month && year == dateIn.year)
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
```

---

> Find Bugs says: This class defines a covariant version of the equals()
>   method, but inherits the normal equals(Object) method defined in the
>   base java.lang.Object class.  The class should probably define a
>   boolean equals(Object) method.

How do I get rid of this bug can anyone help?

Comment: Your `equals` method is not valid. It should be `boolean equals(Object o)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh it's a valid method, it just doesn't override the one in Object.

Comment: @immibis if you are being pedantic, yes. But it's not a valid _`equals`_ method, as that (at least in my opinion) always refers to the one on `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

[`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) should take `Object` as argument, to match the super method it overrides. Use the annotation `@Override` to enforce this.

```
// Equals Method
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (!(o instanceof Date))
        return false;
    Date dateIn = (Date) o;
    if(day == dateIn.day && month == dateIn.month && year == dateIn.year)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are overloading the `equals()` method. This means, there are two actual functions that can be called. Namely, the inherited `equals(Object)` and your `equals(Date)`.

**Overloading** means there are multiple methods with the *same* name but *different* types of arguments.

**Overriding** means you are changing the *implementation* of a method that is defined in a super class (a class you are inheriting from). If you are not directly inheriting from another class, you'll inherit functions from `Object` by default (e.g., as `equals(Object)` in this case).

`@Override` annotation provides compile-time checks and errors, iff there iss no such method to overwrite. This would have happened in your case (as you did overload and not override).

Change your code to

```
// Equals Method
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
   if(this == object) return true;
   if(!(object instanceof Date)) return false;

   Date dateIn = (Date) object;      
   if(day == dateIn.day && month == dateIn.month && year == dateIn.year)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: I edited your answer, please note that overloading != overriding.

Comment: Well, actually he overloaded the function as he introduced ```equals(Date)```.

Comment: It'll be great if you can explain the difference between the two, looks like it'll help OP to understand his mistake.

Comment: Ive tried all the above code in my class, but find bugs is still finding the same bug

Comment: Is it still finding the issue? Did you removed your own ```equals(Date)``` function?

Answer (score 2):

If this `Date` class is some custom `Date` class you wrote, you should change your `equals` method to override Object's equal :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
   if (this == other)
       return true;
   if (!(other instanceof Date))
       return false;
   Date dateIn = (Date) other;
   if(day == dateIn.day && month == dateIn.month && year == dateIn.year)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Otherwise it won't be used properly (since Collections such as `HashMap`, `HashSet`, `ArrayList`, etc... will call the default implementation of `Object`'s `equals` instead of calling your implementation).